# How to display mobile service data in a Grid? MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've added a connection to an MVC site for my Azure mobile service that I've used in another WPF based app.

I'm not too familiar with how the data can be displayed in MVC from a mobile service, can't find any good examples showing how to display the table data on the page, in a grid for example.

Does anyone know how to display the table date on the page? Or can you advise me on what further steps to take in displaying the data?

The code for the Home controller:

```
namespace GesturePhysioWebClient.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Control Panel";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Patient Progress Details.";

            return View();

        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Contact Us.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The toolbox doesn't show any available grid control to add to the page below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>

    <p>
        Patient Records:
        //want to put a grid control or similar here
        //to display the item table records.

    </p>

</article>
```

Added a model for the item table in my model folder like this:

```
namespace GesturePhysioWebClient.Models
{
    class ItemModel
    {
        ////get and set Item table fields
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Exercise { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Painful_Arc_Start { get; set; }
        public string Painful_Arc_End { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Max_Range { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Azure connection showing the Item table:

[image: mobile service]

Comment: Could you post the code of the controller too?

Comment: @HuyHoangPham added the home controller to the above question. What step should I take next to set up displaying the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible but I'm not sure its the best use of Mobile Services.
Firstly make sure you have `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices` installed from `NuGet`

Make sure you have a reference in HomeController to

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices
```

Your Index method would look something like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient("Your mobile service URL",
                                               "Your mobile service access key");
    var itemModelTable = mobileClient.GetTable<ItemModel>();

    var result= await itemModelTable.ToListAsync();

    return View(result);
  }
```

**UPDATE**
For the view you could do something like this

```
@model List<ItemModel>
<article>    
    Patient Records:
    //want to put a grid control or similar here
    //to display the item table records.

  @foreach (var element in Model)
  {
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.User)</p>
  }

</article>
```

or have a look at `@Html.ListBox` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/771999/ASP-Net-MVC-How-to-create-a-ListBox)